# Connecting two raspberry pi through bluetooth with bluez

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez, rfcomm

I'm trying to use this API: https://www.linumiz.com/bluetooth-connectdevice-without-scanning/ to make a connection between two Raspberry PI. I'm using this program like a server such as:

> `pi@raspberrypi:~/bluetoothC $ sudo ./bin/bluez_adapter_connect`
>
> Adapter is Powered "on"

and then, in the client side:

> `pi@raspberrypi:~/bluetoothC $ sudo ./bin/bluez_adapter_connect
>   B8:27:EB:9F:91:A7`
>
> Adapter is Powered "on" Unable to get result:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method
>   "ConnectDevice" with signature "a{sv}" on interface
>   "org.bluez.Adapter1" doesn't exist

But I don't understand this error. I'm doing this correctly? If not, what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the article, ConnectDevice is the new adapter API introduced in BlueZ 5.49. Refer release notes [here](http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-49/) for more details.

This API is still marked as experimental, so you need to run bluetoothd daemon in experimental mode, i.e by passing "-E" as extra argument when starting bluetoothd.

So you need,

1. BlueZ 5.49 or later
2. Run bluetoothd daemon with "-E" option

Comment: `[ /org/bluez/hci0/dev_B8_27_EB_15_3B_24 ]
        Address : B8:27:EB:15:3B:24
        AddressType : public
        Name : raspberrypi
        Alias : raspberrypi
        Paired : 0
        Trusted : 0
        Blocked : 0
        LegacyPairing : 0
        Connected : 1
        UUIDs :
        Adapter : /org/bluez/hci0
        ServicesResolved : 0
        ConnectDevice : /org/bluez/hci0/dev_B8_27_EB_15_3B_24`

the output is this. But I can't make the pairing too? because I'm doing this to exchange information later with: https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html

Comment: but it gives me error as the devices are not connected/paired or whatever

Comment: @PRVS This sample program was written to demonstrate the connection with scanning for the device when device MAC address is know. When you initiate a connection from Host controller or device end, you should run according client agent (auto accept agent) in other end. So that the pairing passes. You should modify the agent here for accepting at both the end.

Comment: I think that an answer to this question will help me to understand: So, I want to make a connection between two raspberry pi to send a message between them. But I want to do that in both ends with "C", if you know what I mean. Is it possible with this API?

Comment: @PRVS Before getting things done in C or DBUS, did you already tried "bluetoothctl"? If not, try pairing the Pi's and try connecting them using bluetoothctl sequence. If done, repeat the same in DBUS flow. C code is simple when you know what you want to do!